# How to call signficantterms aggregation in ElasticSearch 2.2.0 Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregation

I just switched to ElasticSearch 2.2.0, and the addAggregation method in the Java API (SearchRespone#prepareResponse...) seems to have changed, but the docs here show a method that is not working. Perhaps I'm just a rather poor googler.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_bucket_aggregations.html#java-aggs-bucket-terms

This, below, won't compile for obvious reasons (Type mismatch):

```
.setAggregations(AggregationBuilders.significantTerms("termagg").field("item_type").size(100))
          .setFrom(0)
          .setSize(0)
          .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
          .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
          .setExplain(true)
          .execute()
          .actionGet();
```

and since the new .addAggregations method will take an XContent, I tried constructing an XContent object with an XContent builder, but can't make that work either. One of the seemingly infinite permutations of this i have tried looked, and failed, something like this below:

.setAggregations(AggregationBuilders.terms("termagg").field("item_type").size(100).toXContent(XContentBuilder.builder( XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()), ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS))

Does anyone know the right incantation to make this work? I've done it in previous versions, and everything else about my connection, queries, and processing the response is fine.

Thanks!

UPDATE

here is the code that worked...

```
  SignificantTermsBuilder ghgb = AggregationBuilders.significantTerms("type_in_bin").field("item_type");

        SearchResponse response = tc.prepareSearch("someindex")
                .setQuery(qb)
                .addAggregation(ghgb)
                .setFrom(0)
                .setSize(250)
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                .setExplain(true)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

Comment: You have a full example in the official docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_bucket_aggregations.html#java-aggs-bucket-significantterms)

Comment: @Val thanks, will take a lok